# didChangeCameraPosition get bounding box/ rectangle of available coordinates

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios, gmsmapview

How can I retrieve the GMSCoordinateBounds from a GMSCameraPosition? I want to know the visible coordinates on the map (at least Northeast/Southwest points) everytime the user moves the camera as in:

```
(void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didChangeCameraPosition:(GMSCameraPosition *)position
```

Answer (score 17):

```
GMSVisibleRegion visibleRegion = mapView.projection.visibleRegion;
GMSCoordinateBounds *bounds = [[GMSCoordinateBounds alloc] initWithRegion:visibleRegion];

// we've got what we want, but here are NE and SW points
CLLocationCoordinate2D northEast = bounds.northEast;
CLLocationCoordinate2D southWest = bounds.southWest;
```