# How to get my MapContainer bounding box in Codename One

Tags: codenameone

My Codename One app features a MapContainer. I need to show points of interest (POIs) on it which coordinates reside on the server. There can be hundreds (maybe thousands in the future) of such POIs on the server. That's why I would like to only download from the server the POIs that can be shown on the map. Consequently I need to get the map boundaries to pass them to the server.

I read [this for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14700498/android-google-maps-get-boundary-co-ordinates) and this other [SO question for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23770999/didchangecameraposition-get-bounding-box-rectangle-of-available-coordinates) and the key seems to get the map Projection and the map bounding box. However the getProjection() method or the getBoundingBox() seem not to be exposed.

A solution could be to mix the coordinates from `getCameraLocation()` which is the map center and `getZoom()` to infer those boundaries. But it may vary depending on the device (see the shown area can be larger).

How can get the map boundaries in Codename one ?

Any help appreciated,

Cheers,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the javadocs for getCoordAtPosition().   This will be corrected.  getCoordAtPosition() expects absolute coordinates, not relative.

E.g

```java
Coord NE = currentMap.getCoordAtPosition(currentMap.getWidth(), 0); 
Coord SW = currentMap.getCoordAtPosition(0, currentMap.getHeight());
```

Should be

```java
Coord NE = currentMap.getCoordAtPosition(currentMap.getAbsoluteX() + currentMap.getWidth(), currentMap.getAbsoluteY()); 
Coord SW = currentMap.getCoordAtPosition(currentMap.getAbsoluteX(), currentMap.getAbsoluteY() + currentMap.getHeight());
```

I tried this out on the coordinates that you provided and it returns valid results.

**EDIT March 21, 2017** :  It turns out that some of the platforms expected relative coordinates, and others expected absolute coordinates.  I have had to standardize it, and I have chosen to use relative coordinates across all platforms to be consistent with the Javadocs.  So your first attempt:

```java
Coord NE = currentMap.getCoordAtPosition(currentMap.getWidth(), 0); 
Coord SW = currentMap.getCoordAtPosition(0, currentMap.getHeight());
```

Will now work in the latest version of the library.

I have also added another method : `getBoundingBox()` that will get the bounding box for you without worrying about relative/absolute coordinates.

Comment: That's great! Thanks Steve!

Answer (score 1):

This is probably something that can be exposed easily by forking the project and providing a pull request. We're currently working on updating the map component so this is a good time to make changes and add features.

Comment: do you mean the `MapComponent` from `package com.codename1.maps` or the `MapContainer`. The former does not declare `Projection` or `BoundingBox` object and I cannot find the `MapContainer` sources. Would you mind guiding me further?

Comment: `MapContainer` is a part of the native maps cn1lib which is [here](https://github.com/codenameone/codenameone-google-maps).  Since it's implemented as a cn1lib you can also easily edit the native code which is sometimes less intuitive in Codename One itself. It's also not as risky.

Comment: Thanks @Shai. Meanwhile for the same goal I tried something with `getCoordAtPosition` applied to the MapContainer but I don't understand the results. The map center is at (**Lat : 48.8574 ; Lon : 2.0654**), and I tried 

`// Get the map borders`
        `Coord NE = currentMap.getCoordAtPosition(currentMap.getWidth(), 0);
        Coord SW = currentMap.getCoordAtPosition(0, currentMap.getHeight());`

In the simulator I get 
     **Lat SW = 48.8584 lat NE = 48.8612** _(NOK because both lat > map center lat)_
     **Lon SW = 2.0625 lon NE = 2.0679** _(OK)_.
Why is the SW latitude wrong ?

Comment: I'm not a map expert but I recall there are several "projection" types or something like that so maybe the map is using one of those?

Comment: So the method `getCoordAtPosition` does not take the projection into account. I understood from the method name that I would get the lon;lat coord of any xy point on the map. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: It should but it might use a different type of projection than the one used by MapComponent, sorry if I'm vague here... It's not intentional, just ignorance about this specific niche

Comment: I get what you meant now! Thanks for the details! If you're right (the projection in MapContainer is different than in MapComponent) then can it be considered as a bug of `getCoordAtPosition`?

Comment: That's possible, I'm not sure it's something we want to fix though. Personally, I'd align with native maps rather than with MapComponent. We are moving towards using HTML maps in the `MapContainer` instead of MapComponent as the fallback. They look and function better on the devices and now that we have z-ordering in the peers they are a better option

Comment: Do you mean this behaviour only occurs in the simulator (which falls back to MapComponent) and will not occur on the real iOS / Android devices which do use MapContainer ? If so then the problem is solved!

Comment: I don't know, but the coordinates might be valid and you might need to run them thru a projection